# (EF) Mapping Multiple Columns of Same Type To Array/List Property In POCO Class

Tags: entity-framework-core, poco

I have a table with multiple columns (named `Day0`, `Day1` etc) each storing an `INT` and would like to know if it is possible to declare `public Days int[] {get; set;}` in the POCO class and use Fluent API to map each `Day<n>` column to an item in the array rather than declare a separate property for each column.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Indexer property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties#configuring-indexer-properties) in combination with the owned entity.

**YourEntity**

```
public OwnedDays? Days { get; set; } = new();
```

**OwnedDays**

```
public class OwnedDays
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, int?> _data = new Dictionary<string, int?>
    {
        { "0", default },
        { "1", default },
        { "2", default },
        { "3", default },
    };

    public int? this[string key]
    {
        get => _data[key];
        set => _data[key] = value;
    }
}
```

**Context.OnModelCreating**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<YourEntity>().OwnsOne(
    ye => ye.Days,
    d => {
        d.IndexerProperty<int?>("0").HasColumnName("Day0");
        d.IndexerProperty<int?>("1").HasColumnName("Day1");
        d.IndexerProperty<int?>("2").HasColumnName("Day2");
        d.IndexerProperty<int?>("3").HasColumnName("Day3");
    });
```

**Application code**

```
var entity = new YourEntity();
entity.Days["0"] = 0;
entity.Days["1"] = 1;
```

Comment: This seems promising but I am not sure it is exactly what I was thinking of. I don't want to use an indexer on the entity class itself, but rather on a named property like `entity.Days[0]`. Is this the closest I can get?

Comment: I have checked Indexer+Owned entity, for insert works as expected

Comment: So put the indexer on a `Days` entity that is owned by `YourEntity`?